# C/C++/Haskell AMQP server library

Tags: c++, c, haskell, amqp

Are there any known implementation of AMQP broker that can be used as a library? There's an abundance of clients but the broker implementations I've found all want to run as independent processes.

I'm looking into writing something where each Node would be both a broker and a client. An independent broker/ external process isn't an option.

Preferably in C/C++ or Haskell or anything that provides a C like interface that can be linked against.

If not,  any recommended alternatives to AMQP that would fit the bill?

Answer (score 1):

Try [ZerroMQ (ØMQ)](http://zeromq.org/).

Here is [client and server example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#header-10) manual.

And brief implementation from examples repo:

[Server](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/hwclient.c):

```
// Hello World server

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    // Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received Hello\n");
        sleep (1); // Do some 'work'
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Client](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/hwclient.c):

```
// Hello World client
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("Connecting to hello world server...\n");
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");

    int request_nbr;
    for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        char buffer [10];
        printf ("Sending Hello %d...\n", request_nbr);
        zmq_send (requester, "Hello", 5, 0);
        zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received World %d\n", request_nbr);
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this. I know and already use ZMQ but it doesn't offer the guarantees something like AMQP does and we've had problems with it losing data which rules it out as an option but it is effectively the kind of library I was thinking of.

Comment: With AMQP broker you also can lose data (it is damn rare and we don't experience such issues with latest RabbitMQ anymore). And what is wrong to have running amqp broker daemon?

Comment: An external process means something else to manage and maintain but more importantly the application can be changed at run time based on a number of factors without human involvement, an external broker doesn't offer the fine grained control required

Comment: RabbitMQ is very configurable from client (unlike other brokers). You can add, delete exchanges, queues, change bindings in runtime without touching broker config, reboots, etc.

Comment: I agree, you practically never have to touch config files, everything can be done through the API. You have full control.

Answer (score 0):

After asking around I was pointed at [Nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) being done by Martin Sústrik, same dude that did ZMQ. While it doesn't quite offer the guarantees I was after, it seems the architectural changes made to nanomsg from ZMQ makes it easier to manually implement and enforce guarantees.
I'll dig into it more to see but so far it looks promising.